# JSON github serving issue

Tags: json, github-pages

I'm trying to serve a `.json` file on GH pages and it's not accessible.

The file I'm trying to access is at https://andreyden.github.io/data/articles.json

I expect something like https://bioinfobot.github.io/data/2017-05.json

Instead I'm getting a 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to GH servers not loading the file right away. A fue hours later everything was up.